# Firebase database iOS crashing GTMSessionFetcher

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gtmsessionfetcher

I updated firebase and since then my app keeps crashing with the following error

> Fetcher delegate class: NRMAURLSessionTaskDelegate Fetcher made an
>   extra session: GTMSessionFetcher 0x125d53db0  Couldn't assign
>   delegate.
>
> Fetcher delegate class: NRMAURLSessionTaskDelegate
>   -[GTMSessionFetcher setFetcher:forTask:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125d53db0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GTMSessionFetcher
>   setFetcher:forTask:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x125d53db0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18260ad8c 0x1817c45ec 0x182618098 0x1826105c8 0x1824f641c 0x104637b14 0x104613928 0x10461011c
>   0x102d9364c 0x102d96bdc 0x102d95140 0x102d92a54 0x102db3f90
>   0x102db36b0 0x102da0e00 0x105bfd1dc 0x105bfd19c 0x105c0bdfc
>   0x105c006ac 0x105c0bc20 0x105c006ac 0x105c0cd54 0x105c13e38
>   0x18222fe70 0x18222fb08) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

the call that I make and crashes is the following:

```
let reviewsRef = Database.database().reference()
reviewsRef.child("reviews").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: count)
```

I added a debug log and the call is made only once.
It seems the line that the app is crashing is

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Did anything changed regarding configuring Firebase from 4.9 to 5.0 version?

Another update: 
It seems to be working on the Xcode simulator but not on device. Device is iPhone 6s with 11.4

Kind of working since on simulator I receive the whole database instead of only the "reviews" that I am requesting

if the rules are:

```
    {
     "rules": {
        ".read": true,
```

but when I change to:

```
 "rules": {
 "reviews": {
    ".read": true,
```

I get permission denied(on simulator).It has to do maybe with authentication? I understand that those 2 might be two different issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why this happened on the first place. But I created a new project in firebase with exact same rules and it worked... for some reason the specific project became corrupt on firebase side.

Answer (score 0):

`NRMAURLSessionTaskDelegate` indicates usage of *New Relic* - if it worked on a clean project there might be an incompatibility with *Firebase*